# Convert Inherited Permissions into Explicit Permissions from Command-line

Tags: linux, windows, posix, acl

I have a CIFS/SAMBA network share called **Public_Share** on TrueNAS Scale (Debian based) and it's an shared area where everyone on my local network has full access to be able to drop files and folders. Inside of this network share I have a folder called Downloads that contains all of my executable installers for various operating systems, tools, ISO images for spinning up virtual machines etc. I've listed the directory structure in a tree as shown below.

```
Public_Share
    Downloads
        Autoruns
        ISO Images
        ProcessMonitor
        Rufus
```

I'm trying to enable POSIX ACLs on the network share so that there are full permissions and default permissions for new files/directories, but then explicitly set **read** and **execute** permissions only (no write permissions) on the **Downloads** directory and it's child directories so that non-admin users can't delete the contents. I believe what I'm looking for is being able to define explicit permissions which should allow me to separate the permissions from the parent to which from I can then modify the **other** class to remove the **write** permission.

From TrueNAS' CLI the **Downloads** directory currently has the following ACLs:

```
root@FS-Home[~]# getfacl /mnt/pool0/public_dataset/Downloads
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/pool0/public_dataset/Downloads
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:builtin_administrators:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:builtin_administrators:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

From Microsoft Window File Explorer I'm able to remove/block the inheritance from the parent directory (network share) by clicking on the **Disable inheritance** button.
[image]

and then clicking on the **Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object** option.

[image]
I'm able to set my desired permissions and default permissions for new files/directories in the command-line for the network share as a whole, but unfortunately I'm unable to find a way converting Downloads' permissions to explicit permissions from command-line.

```
# Public_Share
    # clear ACLs
        setfacl -R -b /mnt/pool0/public_dataset

    # Set default UNIX permissions
        chown -R root:root /mnt/pool0/public_dataset
        chmod -R 0777 /mnt/pool0/public_dataset

    # Allow built-in administrators full permissions and add full permissions to default permissions for new files/directories
        setfacl -R -m g:builtin_administrators:rwx /mnt/pool0/public_dataset
        setfacl -d -R -m group:builtin_administrators:rwx /mnt/pool0/public_dataset
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

The desired would look like this:

```
root@FS-Home[~]# getfacl /mnt/pool0/public_dataset/Downloads
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/pool0/public_dataset/Downloads
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
group::rwx
group:root:rwx
group:builtin_administrators:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:root:rwx
default:group:builtin_administrators:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe I achieved the same result with a couple of commands.

It seems that explicitly modifying the write permission on the **Downloads** directory to denied whilst the parent directory has granted write permissions seems to force the entire directory to stop inheriting permissions from the network share. I'm essentially negating the write permission against itself on the **other** permission class.

```
setfacl -R -m other:r-x /mnt/pool0/public_dataset/Downloads
setfacl -d -R -m other:r-x /mnt/pool0/public_dataset/Downloads
```